# Navigation en Appdelegate o SceneDelegate Xcode 11?

Tags: swift, xcode

como puedo crear un navigation en Xcode 11 sin usar SwiftUI... ya que usando el constructor:

```
   UINavigationController(rootViewController: View)
```

no me funciona y lo he puesto tanto en el appdelegate como en el sceneDelegate... y se ve de la siguiente manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y usando el appdelegate:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he buscado en foros y google pero no he encontrado nada al respecto... me gustaría crearlo sin usar SwiftUI, ya que con SwiftUI se crea desde el View... y usando:

```
  UIHostingController(root: myView)
```

pero no es lo que estoy buscando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la manera de hacerlo:

en SceneDelegate:

```
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

          guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
          window = UIWindow(frame: scene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
          window?.windowScene = scene
          window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

          let view = ViewController()
          let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: view)
          window?.rootViewController = navigation
}
```